# I need to show a element in a table when hovering another next to it with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Table</title>
  <style>
  table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Short Name</th>
        <th>Name</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>N1</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>N2</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>N3</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>N4</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I hover for example, N1 in the first row, the second one shows NAME1 next to N1. I can't use jquery or css, just javascript. I need to make this work 1 by 1, not the whole table, so If the mouse is on N1 and I move it to N2, NAME1 dissapears and NAME2 shows. I don't know if it's better to control the second row with html or javascript I mean, build in HTML the second row or build it with javascript. Also, when the mouse is not hovering anything in the first row, the second must be clear.

Comment: NAME1 , NAME2 are like static text?

Comment: you dont need javascript for it

Comment: @SandeepNayak yes, static text, just like the other row.

Comment: and any reason why you cannot use `jQuery` or `css`?

Comment: @SandeepNayak I'm doing this as a "learn up" for the university so I didn't know how to use jQuery or css already. Would be nice just js and html, if not, I will go with css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need JS for this. It would be long and messy. Here is a very simple CSS solution:

```
table, th, td { border: 1px solid black; }
td:last-child{visibility:hidden;}
tr:hover td:last-child{visibility:visible;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wsrp8rky/

Comment: I accept your answer. You are right, css is pretty simple and clean in this code. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks Pablo - hover effects are always easier with CSS!